# Getting PostgreSQL error when using QGIS Cloud plugin

Tags: qgis, postgresql, qgis-cloud

I created a qgis cloud account and installed the plugin. When I attempted to Upload Data using the plugin, I got the following error:

> postgreSQL exception:
>
> ERROR:  "MD5" authentication with pgpool failed for user
> "database_name"

Any ideas on how to fix this error so I can upload data?

Comment: Please contact the plugin authors. As far as I know it's still an experimental plugin and they will appreciate any bug reports they get.

Comment: The QGIS Cloud plugin is working properly for me now! I contacted someone from Sourcepole and a database access problem was fixed.

Comment: How was it fixed btw? It would be great if you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted. That way, other people would know that it is the solution to this particular problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem with QGIS . I use different option as well like Jelastic , Heroku and other. And I found more reliable options are available. Like Jelastic never showed me any issue while using PostgreSQL for Java or PHP.

Following links may help -

http://jelastic.com/docs/connection-to-postgresql

http://jelastic.com/docs/connection-to-postgresql-for-php

I found it preety easy to implement.